# 404 auth0 update user (PUT)

Tags: angularjs, http-status-code-404, put, auth0

I keep hitting a 404 "user not found" error when trying to make a PUT request with auth0.

I'm trying to update a user and making this API call with the exact endpoint their docs told me to use.

When making the call from their docs (they have a built in test), everything works fine with the body I send and I receive a 200 success message.

When I try making the same call from my app, I keep getting a 404 user not found error.

However, when I use the same endpoint with the same `user_id` to GET from my app, everything works fine (proving my cliendID is configured correctly).

Why is this failing?

```
var updateAuthUser = function(){
    var request = {
        "user_metadata": {
            "springboardID": 100055
        }
    }

    var update = $http.put('https://app36591925.auth0.com/api/v2/users/auth0%7C5606b3c4b0c70b49698612fc', request);

    update.then(function(response) {
            console.log("update success", response);
        }, function(response) {
            console.log("update failure", response);
        });
    return update;
}
```

Working GET request:

```
var getAuthUser = function(){
    $http.get('https://app36591925.auth0.com/api/v2/users/auth0|5606b3c4b0c70b49698612fc')
        .then(function(response){
            console.log("response", response);

            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(response);
            return deferred.promise;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The endpoint to update a user is to be called with PATCH, not PUT.

https://auth0.com/docs/api/v2#!/Users/patch_users_by_id

The correct response to return in this case would be 405 Method Not Allowed, but hapi does not yet support this. See https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/1534.